# How create test for dio timeout

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, dio

I am trying to create a test for timeout using Dio, I expect get DioError with type CONNECT_TIMEOUT then throw a custom exception

My test I mock Dio with Mockito and try throw DioError

```
test(
      'Should throw [ConnectionTimeOutException] when reach timeout',
      () async {
        //arange
        when(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
        when(mockDio.post(paths.login, data: tParams.toJson())).thenThrow(
            (_) async => DioError(type: DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT));
        //act
        final call = loginDataSource.login;
        //assert
        expect(() => call(params: tParams),
            throwsA(TypeMatcher<ConnectTimeOutException>()));
      },
    );
```

My data source class:

```
class LoginDataSourceImpl implements LoginDataSource {
  final Dio dio;
  final NetworkInfo networkInfo;

  LoginDataSourceImpl({@required this.dio, @required this.networkInfo});

  @override
  Future<CredencialModel> login({@required Params params}) async {
    if (!await networkInfo.isConnected) {
      throw NoNetworkException();
    }

    try {
      final response = await dio.post(paths.login, data: params.toJson());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return CredencialModel.fromJson(response.data);
      } else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        final error = ResponseError.fromJson(response.data);
        switch (error.error) {
          case 'invalid_request':
            throw InvalidRequestException();
            break;
          case 'invalid_device':
            throw InvalidDeviceException();
            break;
          case 'invalid_user_credentials':
            throw InvalidUserCredentialException();
            break;
          case 'user_disabled':
            throw UserDisableException();
          default:
            throw UnknowException();
        }
      } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        throw ServerException();
      } else {
        throw UnknowException();
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {
        throw ConnectTimeOutException();
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT) {
      } else {
        throw UnknowException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the test is:

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'ConnectTimeOutException'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<CredencialModel>>
   Which: threw <Closure: (dynamic) => DioError>
stack package:mockito/src/mock.dart 385:7
```

How can i solve this issue and create a Timeout test with Dio?

Comment: You might try throwing an `await` on that `call` there.

Comment: Also `thenThrow` takes whatever object you passed to it and throws it as an error. You gave it a closure object. That closure doesn't get called, just thrown. Change it to just `thenThrow(DioError(type: DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT))`.

Comment: You are right @Abion47, thanks, please put you comment as a answer so i can mark as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.

First, you are testing an `async` method but you are not `await`ing it. This is going to cause the raw `Future` object to be returned to the `expect` function which is going to consider it a successful call, even if the future ends up throwing an error. You will need to `await` your call, although doing so as a closure passed to `expect` is awkward. I would suggest wrapping the asynchronous call in a try/catch instead.

Second, you are providing a closure to Mockito's `thenThrow` method. This method takes whatever you give to it and uses it as the actual thrown value, so it isn't going to call the closure you passed to it - it will just throw it as-is.

Fixing these both, you end up with this:

```dart
test(
  'Should throw [ConnectionTimeOutException] when reach timeout',
  () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockNetworkInfo.isConnected)
      .thenAnswer(true);
    when(mockDio.post(paths.login, data: tParams.toJson()))
      .thenThrow(DioError(type: DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT));

    // act
    final call = loginDataSource.login;

    // assert
    try {
      await call(params: tParams);
    } catch(e) {
      expect(e, isInstanceOf<ConnectTimeOutException>());
    }
  },
);
```