# Flutter how to unit test Dio 401, 500 responses

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dio

Currently I'm testing 200 responses as following

```
final dio = Dio();
final dioAdapter = DioAdapter();
dio.httpClientAdapter = dioAdapter;
const path = 'https://endpoint.com';

test('Loading shows when user taps set up trading account', () async {
  dioAdapter
    ..onPost(
      path,
      (request) => request.reply(204, {}),
    );

  final onGetResponse = await dio.post(path);

  when(_tradingAccountService.setUpTradingAccount())
      .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Stream.value(HttpResponse(onGetResponse.data, onGetResponse)));
  await signUpViewModel.setUpTradingAccount();
  expect(signUpViewModel.isSettingUpTradingAccount, true);
});
```

But when I try to test 401 or 500, dio throws `HttpStatusError`

```
 final dioError = DioError(
        error: {'message': 'Some beautiful error!'},
        requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '/foo'),
        response: Response(
          statusCode: 500,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '/foo'),
        ),
    type: DioErrorType.response,
  );

  dioAdapter.onPost(
    path,
    (request) => request.throws(500, dioError),
  );
```

I was hoping to do something like this

```
 when(_tradingAccountService.setUpTradingAccount())
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Stream.value(HttpResponse(204)));
```

Those didn't help [How create test for dio timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768709/how-create-test-for-dio-timeout) and
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/test/mock_adapter.dart

Answer (score 5):

### Use [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter),package for mocking `Dio` requests.

You can simply replace your injected `Dio`'s `httpClientAdapter` with `DioAdapter()` of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter):

example from [examples](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter/example) of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter)

### Usage

Here is the basic usage scenario of the package (via `DioAdapter`):

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http_mock_adapter/http_mock_adapter.dart';

void main() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  final dioAdapter = DioAdapter();

  dio.httpClientAdapter = dioAdapter;

  const path = 'https://example.com';

  dioAdapter
      ..onGet(
        path,
        (request) => request.reply(200, {'message': 'Successfully mocked GET!'}),
      )
      ..onGet(
        path,
        (request) => request.reply(200, {'message': 'Successfully mocked POST!'}),
      );

  final onGetResponse = await dio.get(path);
  print(onGetResponse.data); // {message: Successfully mocked GET!}

  final onPostResponse = await dio.post(path);
  print(onPostResponse.data); // {message: Successfully mocked POST!}
}
```

#### Note:

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321828/unit-test-how-to-mock-parameters-of-third-party-library-class-dio-in-flutter/64935059#64935059) was a fixed kinda issue please take a look at it there, I guess it would be helpful.